# Applying voice effects on recorded audio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to know some way in which we can change a recorded audio into some celebrity or cartoon character's voice.
I've done the audio recording part but looking for some help in applying voice effects on that recorded audio.

I've done recording the audio and saving in internal storage. I just need help in applying voice effects.